# Path to current file in Dart

Tags: dart

How can I get the path to the current file? (similar to the `__FILE__` constant in PHP or macro in C) For example:

**a.dart**:

```dart
import './b.dart';

void main() => print(path());
```

**b.dart**:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

String path() => Platform.script.toFilePath();
```

The above code prints the path to the invoking script, **a.dart**. How can I change **b.dart** to get the path to **b.dart** instead, such that wherever I call `path()` from within the project, I'll always get the correct path to **b.dart**?

Answer (score 5):

This may not work in all cases (I means the platforms and executable formats), but it is as easy as shelling pears:

```
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  final frame = _frame(); // <==== /E:/prj/dart_test/bin/main.dart at line 4
  print('file: ${frame.uri.path}');
  print('lime: ${frame.line}');
}

Frame _frame() {
  return Frame.caller(1);
}
```

Result:

```
file: /E:/prj/dart_test/bin/main.dart
lime: 4
```